# Redis - copy keys from server/s to new cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I wanted to migrate data from several standalone Redis servers to a single cluster in the cloud.

Redis version of source servers: 2.6

I've looked into different approaches:

**REPLICAOF**

This is not an option since the new target cluster does not allow the use of the REPLICAOF command.

**Using a tool that supports client-side replication**

Tools like RIOT or Redis-Shake cannot be used since the commands 'SCAN', and 'PSYNC' have only been available since 2.8

**MIGRATE command**

I'm thinking of using `MIGRATE` command along with `KEYS`.

Ideally, I don't want to delete the source key.

However, the `MIGRATE [COPY]` option is only available since 3.0.0

And the `MIGRATE [KEYS]` option is only available since 3.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me:

- Dump RDB files for all the source servers
- Write those RDB files to the target cluster using redis-migrate-tool.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several options you can choose from:

- Upgrade to high version Redis.
- Use RedisShake to [replay dump.rdb files](https://tair-opensource.github.io/RedisShake/en/reader/rdb_reader.html).
- Use a higher version Redis as a slave of the 2.6 version, and use RedisShake to export data from the higher version Redis.